# cannot find id to delete data laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i try to delete data using destroy() method of resource controller, but can't delete data, when i use dump and die, id can't be found, what should i do?

this is my controller:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
    User::destroy($user->id);
    return redirect('/dashboard/administrators')->with('success', 'Admin has been deleted');
}
```

this is my route:

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/administrators', DashboardAdministratorController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

and this is my delete form:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>
        <form action="/dashboard/administrators/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
              @method('delete')
              @csrf
              <button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure?')">Deactive</button>
               </form>
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You working with permissions, roles?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes, i did.

Comment: Then check first if the user which want to delete the admin, has the permission to delete the admin. what is your response?

Answer (score 3):

You using route model binding. Then you can use the Laravel `delete()`function.

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
    $user->delete();
    return redirect('/dashboard/administrators')->with('success', 'Admin has been deleted');
}
```

Comment: His route doesn't include the parameter

Comment: @zanderwar If you use resource Laravel automaticly bind the Model.

Comment: Ah, spent my life in lumen, looking forward to the upgrade, cheers.

Comment: @zanderwar Small Note: But only for the standard methods that resource supports (show, destroy, edit etc.). For your own routes, you have to create your own route, where you then specify the model in the url. I have to try out Lumen :-)

Comment: Lumen only faster than Laravel if you don't have Laravel + Octane (Taylor said himself). They're also gonna stop supporting it soon so I wouldn't bother haha, thanks again